# match string between two symbols and replace

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have a file with the many links like this:

```
http://example.com/mall/mall/detail3.jsp?proID=2114280
http://example.com/mall/member/member/bookshelves/add.jsp?proID=3354136&productName=something
http://example.com/mall/bestbookTW//mall/detail3.jsp?proID=3435839&c=532166&id=954325
```

And I want it to become this:

```
http://example.com/mall/mall/detail3.jsp?proID=FUZZ
http://example.com/mall/member/member/bookshelves/add.jsp?proID=FUZZ&productName=FUZZ
http://example.com/mall/bestbookTW//mall/detail3.jsp?proID=FUZZ&c=FUZZ&id=FUZZ
```

How can I do this with sed or grep or awk?

Comment: Between which symbols?

Comment: @RudiC Between `=` and (`&` or line break).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `perl` approach:

```
$ perl -pe 's/=(.+?)(&|$)/=FUZZ$2/g' file 
http://example.com/mall/mall/detail3.jsp?proID=FUZZ
http://example.com/mall/member/member/bookshelves/add.jsp?proID=FUZZ&productName=FUZZ
http://example.com/mall/bestbookTW//mall/detail3.jsp?proID=FUZZ&c=FUZZ&id=FUZZ
```

The idea is to replace all strings following a `=` and until the next `&` or the end of the line (`$`) with `FUZZ`.

To modify the original file instead of printing to standard output, use `-i`:

```
perl -i -pe 's/=(.+?)(&|$)/=FUZZ$2/g' file
```

Alternatively, with `sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/=([^&]*)/=FUZZ/g' file 
http://example.com/mall/mall/detail3.jsp?proID=FUZZ
http://example.com/mall/member/member/bookshelves/add.jsp?proID=FUZZ&productName=FUZZ
http://example.com/mall/bestbookTW//mall/detail3.jsp?proID=FUZZ&c=FUZZ&id=FUZZ
```

Again, use `-i` to edit the original file:

```
sed -i -E 's/=([^&]*)/=FUZZ/g' file
```

And you can use the same approach with `perl` too:

```
perl -i -lpe 's/=([^&]*)/=FUZZ/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also

```
awk 'gsub("=[^&]*", "=FUZZ")' file 
http://example.com/mall/mall/detail3.jsp?proID=FUZZ
http://example.com/mall/member/member/bookshelves/add.jsp?proID=FUZZ&productName=FUZZ
http://example.com/mall/bestbookTW//mall/detail3.jsp?proID=FUZZ&c=FUZZ&id=FUZZ
```